# server 2012 r2 data drive showing as full... but it really isn't?

Tags: windows, storage

all,

was transferring some data to a new Server 2012 R2 machine. I used both robocopy and another file transfer utility and got the same result.

there is a very large data volume, 15 TB on this server. anyway, I transferred about 50 MB of data to the new volume and I started getting "low disk space" messages on the server. right-clicked and looked at properties for those folders and they are showing almost 15 TB in size which is strange because I checked the source server and they really are only taking up 50 MB.

I dont know where to start on this, anyone seen this before? if it makes a difference I am transferring NTFS permissions on both utilities from the source to the new server and i am transferring using an account that has full control permissions on the source folder. so I do not know what the trouble is. I formatted the big volume and tried again and got the same result both times. thanks

Comment: Are they sparse files?

Comment: Please download and run [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) of the destination server and post here the result.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen in the following scenarios:

- You are copying a directory that contains "reparse points" in it, such as a user profile or a junction to a cluster storage volume.  Reparse points are similar in concept to symlinks and hard links in Unix/Linux filesystems.  Despite being completely normal in the *nix world, and despite the fact that NTFS has supported them for over 20 years, they're (***still!***) a bit of a foreign concept in the Windows world.  Most file copy utilities (including Windows Explorer itself) do not handle them correctly and will try to copy the data that the link points to rather than the link itself.  In this case, you will need to use the `/SL` argument in your `robocopy` command.
- The source contains sparse files.  A sparse file is a very big file that contains mostly empty space.  The OS efficiently stores such files by only allocating disk space for the blocks that actually contain data.  Some database files and virtual hard disk files are created as sparse files.  The problem is that if you copy a sparse file, it will be expanded out to its full size.  **You cannot copy sparse files in Windows without using a 3rd-party utility**.  I can't recommend any because I've never used them before.  [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/657780/copymove-sparse-files-on-ntfs-with-windows) on SuperUser has one you can try.
- The source filesystem contains errors in it.  Sometimes the volume bitmap or MFT index can be corrupt and misrepresent the actual data blocks that a file occupies (or reports as free).  Such subtle errors don't cause problems when reading the file but can wreak havoc when trying to copy or write to them.  In this case, you should perform a `chkdsk` on both volumes before copying.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a RAID configuration? Check Hard Drives.
Check event logs with https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-event-logs-errors-and-6871f163

And look for most frequent errors and also for all related to hard drives.